# To the nearest order of magnitude, what is the average number of licenses per Salesforce org?

Tags: licenses, org, userlicense

I recognize that this is impossible to give a accurate answer to - I am looking for the right order of magnitude - 10? 100? 1000? Let's assume for the sake of argument that we are talking about the Enterprise edition, although numbers for each edition would be much better ...

Thanks,

John

Comment: It'd probably be better to ask salesforce.com directly, since I don't know of a public resource that shows exact numbers. I remember many years ago they celebrated their 2 millionth paid subscriber, and I'd hazard a guess they're at least somewhere between 4 to 5 million subscribers now, not including their acquisitions, such as Heroku, Data.com, etc. I'd wager that *most* organizations above 25 users are at least Enterprise Edition, and I've heard that there is a 100% saturation of premier support/unlimited edition at around the 500 subscriber mark.

Comment: Even that is a big step forward - thanks! I can divide their annual subscription revenue by 5MM subscribers and ... get a number I can work with.